# SSRS date parameter format changes when executing report

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, datepicker, regional-settings

I have a report with date parameter. The default value is `today()` which for this example is *7th of October 2018*.
The date in parameter box is displayed in US format `(10-07-2018)`.

When I hit "Show report" day and month in the parameter box switches places (changes to 07-10-2018).
When I hit "Show report" again, they switch places again.

Of course, I would prefer it to be displayed in UK format and stop switching places.

When day >12 then this does not happen.
When I select the date from the calendar, it is even more bizarre. (I have 2 date parameters). The date displayed is in US format (unless day>12 then stays correct) but also switches day and month for the second parameter.

UPDATE: even stranger: using function dateserial(2018,10,7) gives:

- 7th of October in dataset fileter (correct)
- 10th of July in Parameter box (default value)

As if thre qas different locale settings for parameters and body of raport.

It concerned all reports on the server and tested on two clients.
Windows server language is Polish (for our purposes may be considered the same as the UK).
Regional settings on the server are Polish.
Regional settings on IE are Polish
Default date format in report builder (one with *) is  07.10.2018 (like the UK)
The language on the report is set to PL-pl
The language on the database is Polish
Microsoft SQL Server  and Reporting Services Version 13.0.4224.16

Answer (score 0):

If you format your column the right way (date format) but your language settings (global) are emtpy you get your dates displayed randomly. So you always need, both the language settings **and** the format for the columns, then the dates will always show like you set them.

Click on the gray area of your report (**Report Properties**). Then look under **Localization > Language**. Check if the **Language** property is empty. If its empty put in your needed date format.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post above the language on the report is set to PL-pl

Comment: Oh sorry yes, my bad. Can you try language settings + in the textbox expression `=Format(CDate(Fields!YourDate.Value), "dd.MM.yyyy")` + textbox properties under number set to date format. If this combination will not work then I am at a loss.

Comment: Again - my problem concerns parameter not textbox.

Comment: Its the same with textboxes, they also have the number property. The same goes for the `Format()` funciton. `=Format(CDate(Parameters!YourDate.Value), "MM-dd-yyyy")`

Comment: Tried that. If I select this format I get error. If I cdate it I get US format again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I had the same issue and wanted to update, that for me, the date was giving the same error as you when using the reportbuilder, but was working properly when uploading the report and viewing from report server.

also, in report builder it was just how it was showing the date picker parameter after submitting, it was still using what I originally set